# Automate Local Build and Run of Projects in Intellij

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-14, cicd

I have a project with 12 subprojects in Intellij as it can be seen in the picture

[image: Project Structure]

Eureka Server, Spring API Gateway and then 10 Java Spring projects (microsservices). All using Maven.

Everytime I need to run some integration test, I need to start manually all of them. First Eureka,  after it's on, start API gateway and then the others.

I've searched the web but wasn't able to find any script to automate this. Is there a way??

Comment: Have you looked at the `cargo` plugin?

Comment: I gave up on this and went to create all the services as Docker containers.